# Filtering user list by department (PrincipalSearcher)

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I want to find all users which belongs to one department. But there are no options in the user principal for filtering the department. How can I realize that? It is already working great to find users.

When I use DisplayName where the department is written as well I get an time-out error.

```
    private void FindFromGroupName()
    {
        string departement = _departement;

        // Create the context for the principal object. 
        PrincipalContext ctx;
        ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

        // Create an in-memory user object to use as the query example.
        UserPrincipal u = new UserPrincipal(ctx);

        // Set properties on the user principal object.
        u.Surname = "Doe";
        //u.DisplayName = "*" + departement + "*";

        // Create a PrincipalSearcher object to perform the search.
        PrincipalSearcher ps = new PrincipalSearcher();

        // Tell the PrincipalSearcher what to search for.
        ps.QueryFilter = u;

        var _results = ps.FindAll();

        foreach (UserPrincipal whatever in _results)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(whatever.Name.ToUpper() + ":      \t\t" + whatever.DisplayName + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
```

EDIT:
If I just filter like this:

```
u.DisplayName = "*" + departement + "*";
```

Then I get the following error:

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: {"The time limit for this request was exceeded.\r\n"}

The Display Name looks Like this: John Doe (Departement/GroupName)

It probably takes to long to search through. But the I don't know how to analyse my company network. And I couldn't find an entry which holds the departement in the userPrincipal. Is there away to understand accounts better. How can I create a self created filter?

Note the DistinguishedName looks like this: CN=(1),OU=(2),OU=Useraccounts,OU=(3),DC=(4),DC=(5),DC=com

Explanation
(1):accountname
(2):First Letter of Surname
(3):City
(4):Country
(5):Company name

Comment: We need some more information about your models. What is the exception?
Can you try this:
`whatever?.Name.ToUpper() ?? "unknown"` and 
`whatever?.DisplayName` ?? "unknown"

Comment: Are these informations helpful in EDIT?